# X-Appengine-Country header shows wrong country

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>functions-framework-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

**POM dependency given above**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;

import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpFunction;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpRequest;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpResponse;

public abstract class CommonGCF implements HttpFunction {

    private static final String name = CommonGCF.class.getName();

    protected String m_Client_IP = null;
    protected String m_Client_Country = null;
    protected String m_Client_Region = null;
    protected String m_Client_City = null;
    protected Instant m_api_invocationTime_UTC = null;
    protected ZoneId m_Client_ZoneId = null;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public CommonGCF() {
    }

    @Override
    public void service(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) throws Exception {

        m_api_invocationTime_UTC = Instant.now();
        m_Client_IP = request.getFirstHeader("X-Forwarded-For").get();
        m_Client_Country = request.getFirstHeader("X-Appengine-Country").get();
        m_Client_Region = request.getFirstHeader("X-Appengine-Region").get();
        m_Client_City = request.getFirstHeader("X-Appengine-City").get();
        m_Client_ZoneId = this.getZoneId(m_Client_Country);
    }

    protected ZoneId getZoneId(String m_Client_Country2) {
        System.out.println("received m_Client_Country=" + m_Client_Country2);
        if (m_Client_Country2.equalsIgnoreCase("IN")) {
            System.out.println("returning Asia/Kolkata");
            return ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
        }
        System.out.println("returning UTC");
        return ZoneId.of("UTC");
    }

}
```

`m_Client_Country = request.getFirstHeader("X-Appengine-Country").get();`

returns TW when i invoke my cloud function from India.

when i check for my ip using other services it is showing correctly as India.

No VPN used. It was working until yesterday.

log from Google log console

> 2020-09-23 16:17:15.143 IST RegisterGetProfile am11zdsz2weq received
> m_Client_Country2=TW

Any guidance?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? If the issue confirms I will open a bug with the Cloud product team.

Comment: @Jaroslav have added a class that can be loaded as google cloud function and invoked to show this error. As i said, it was showing IN (for India) but now it is showing TW (for Taiwan) Thanks.

Comment: Have you added something to pom.xml too?

Comment: added in the question at the top @Jaroslav. Thanks

Comment: received m_Client_Country2=TW still returns Taiwan when invoked from India. Can we rely on this parameter to plan our country specific acitivities? Any luck @Jaroslav

Comment: I am consistenly getting TW, another user from same city in India is getting IN

Comment: Trying to reproduce this code in GCF and always getting an error.